# Set background for just one cell in a dynamic TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `TableView` with dynamic prototypes and want the first cell to have a different background than the others.

My attempt was to add

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "firstCellBackground"))
}
```

in

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

This is actually kind of working. The first cell gets the different background, but as soon I start to scroll, a few other cells get the background as well. :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot use half-logic; you must completely state what the background view is for _every_ row, because the same cell will be used for many different rows (which is why you see other cells getting the background).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` instances are typically reused for performance reasons; that cell which initially displayed row 0 might later display row 11 for example. If you use a UITableViewCell subclass, you can implement `prepareForReuse()` in which `backgroundView` can be cleared. Or you can try this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "firstCellBackground"))
} else {
    cell.backgroundView = nil
}
```